# Determining the type of isolated singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by

> $$f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}.$$

My task is to find the isolated singularities of $f$ and determine their type. I know that $z=1$ is a pole of order $2$ by inspection. But for $z=0$, it's not so simple. What's the best method for determining what type of isolated singularity is at $z=0$?

Comment: What keeps you from evaluating $0$ the same way you did $1$?

Comment: Because of the $e^z-1$ term. Evaluating $f(0)$ would give $\frac00$.

Comment: I don't get it. You can't evaluate $f(1)$ either, so why are you doing so for $0$?

Comment: I just thought that because when you evaluate a pole, only the denominator is zero.

Comment: By definition, a complex number $w$ is said to be a pole of order $k$ with respect to $f$, if $w$ is a boundary point of the domain of $f$ and $0\neq\lim \limits_{z\to w}\left(\left|z^kf(z)\right|\right)<\infty\land \lim \limits_{z\to w}\left(\left|z^{k+1}f(z)\right|\right)=0$. Taking $w=1$, it's easy to check that it is indeed a pole of order $2$. Since you have no idea what $k$ might be when $w=0$, don't give it any value yet and analyze $\lim _\limits{z\to 0}\left(z^kf(z)\right)$. Does this help you?

Comment: What about if $z=0$ is not a pole?

Comment: I forgot about that in my previous comment. Any singularity $w$ which isn't a pole is said to be *essential* when $\lim \limits_{z\to w}\left(\left|z^kf(z)\right|\right)=\infty$ for any natural number $k$ and it said to be removable when $\lim \limits_{z\to w}\left(f(z)\right)$ exists finitely.

Answer (score 1):

Around $z=0$ we have :

$$e^z-1=z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}+\dots$$

$$\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{6}+\dots$$

$$\frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{z}{2(z-1)^2}+\frac{z^2}{6(z-1)^2}+\dots$$

$$\frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}=1+2z+3z^2+\dots+\frac{z}{2}+z^2+\frac{3z^3}{2}+\dots+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\dots$$

$$\frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}=1+\frac{5z}{2}+\frac{25z^2}{6}+\dots$$

So $0$ is a removable singularity.